# Eclipse formatter automatically inserts two blank lines after package declaration

Tags: java, eclipse

Am using Eclipse Neon 3 and was making my usual edits to the formatter when I noticed that everytime I create a new class, it creates two new (or blank) lines between the package declaration and the actual class itself!

```
package com.myapp;


public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

How to setup the Eclipse formatter to only include one blank line (initially), especially if there's no import declarations used yet, like this:

```
package com.myapp;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Been trying to fix this myself and would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Review the code template that was set up in Eclipse by opening up `Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Templates` and configure the generated code for `New Java Files` under the `Code` header.

The default template given provided was

```
${filecomment}
${package_declaration}

${typecomment}
${type_declaration}
```

and the generated code as follows

```
package com.personal.test.com.personal.test;

public class AppTest {

}
```

If the template was modified to this, note the extra blank lines.

```
${filecomment}
${package_declaration}



${typecomment}
${type_declaration}
```

The following is generated

```
package com.personal.test.com.personal.test;



public class AppTestWithSpaces {

}
```